# Is it possible to get a consistent look and feel from a java GWT and rails html/jquery application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, gwt, styling

We are developing a large enterprise java(Spring) GWT application that will contain tree controls, data grids, rich text editors, etc.  We have not decided on a specific look and feel for this application so it is flexible for the purposes of this question.

It is important that we have a consistent look and feel in all our client facing web applications.  We are now starting to develop a completely different web application and would like to do it in rails 3.  When we have to use a rich UI control such as a tree or rich text editor we will probably find a suitable JQuery UI component for it.

1)  How feasible is the idea of building a rails 3 app with a similar look and feel to a GWT app?

2)  Do you have any suggestions of how to achieve this?